# How do create a user in microsoft graph with Go

Tags: go, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to write an api that lets me create users (more functionality later) in my azure app registration. I have added `User.ReadWrite.All` permission in the api

I call `setuptAzure` in main.go which creates a client and `main.go` adds it to my handlers functions.

Then the handler `createUser` tries to create a user using the client. Fake data for now.

When running the `createUser` I get this error :

```
"error status code received from the API"
```

I am struggling with logging the status code which would help with debugging

```golang
package main

func setupAzure() *msgraphsdk.GraphServiceClient {
    // print vars
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    TenantId := os.Getenv("TENANT_ID")
    ClientId := os.Getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    ClientSecret := os.Getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")

    // Create a new ClientSecretCredential
    cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(
        TenantId,
        ClientId,
        ClientSecret,
        nil,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Create a new GraphServiceClient
    client, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClientWithCredentials(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return client
}

func main() {

    client := setupAzure()

    log.Println("Creating handlers")
    h := handlers.NewHandler(client)

    log.Println("Setting routes up")
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/users", h.RegisterUser)
    r.GET("/", h.HelloWorld)

    log.Println("running server on http://localhost:8080")
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return
    } // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    graphmodels "github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/models"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func (h Handler) RegisterUser(c *gin.Context) {
    domain := os.Getenv("DOMAIN")

    requestBody := graphmodels.NewUser()
    accountEnabled := true
    requestBody.SetAccountEnabled(&accountEnabled)
    displayName := "Adele Vance"
    requestBody.SetDisplayName(&displayName)
    mailNickname := "AdeleV"
    requestBody.SetMailNickname(&mailNickname)
    userPrincipalName := "AdeleV@" + domain
    requestBody.SetUserPrincipalName(&userPrincipalName)
    passwordProfile := graphmodels.NewPasswordProfile()
    forceChangePasswordNextSignIn := true
    passwordProfile.SetForceChangePasswordNextSignIn(&forceChangePasswordNextSignIn)
    password := "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    passwordProfile.SetPassword(&password)
    requestBody.SetPasswordProfile(passwordProfile)

    result, err := h.graphClient.Users().Post(context.Background(), requestBody, nil)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    log.Println(result)

    // Return a success message
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "User created successfully"})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by changing api permissions from `delegated` to `application`